# How do I dynamically select parameter with crystal report

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have been working on getting a report out for long without success.

I have a report that select based on parameter fields of date and boolean. Currently I have to create 3 reports. One based on dates, one based on the boolean and one based on both.

However, I want my report to be able to select all dates if the user does not input date in the parameter or select all booleans if user does not select one.

Currently I used this

```
if ({?Start Date} = DateTimeValue('') or {?End Date} =DateTimeValue('')) then
   {rectReport.Call date} in DateTimeValue ('1753-01-01 00:00:00') to CurrentDateTime
else 
   ({rectReport.Call date} in {?Start Date} to {?End Date}) and {rectReport.EngineDown} = {?Engine Down}
```

The basic Idea I am looking for is that the user can decide to select only one parameter instead of the two.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks,

Bimbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Crystal 2008 you have the option of making parameters optional. What you could do is create one report with both parameters and then set both parameters as optional. In your record selection formula you could do something like this:

```
(if  (HasValue({?Startdate}) and HasValue({?Enddate}))
        then {table.datefield} in {?Startdate} to {?Enddate}
    else {table.datefield} in {defaultstartdate} to {defaultenddate})

and (if HasValue({?BoolParam}) then {table.boolfield} = {?BoolParam}
    else {table.boolfield} = {defaultbool})
```

If you wanted to select ALL tables if the user did not input the parameter, you could just omit the else-statements.

(note: Sorry if that syntax isn't correct (I am just getting back into CR again), but you get the idea.)

EDIT: Since optional parameters aren't available in CR10, couldn't you just use parameter default values for the dates instead? For the boolean, you could just make a parameter with 3 values: true, false, and "all" and then default to the "all" value when running the report.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I got the Ideaa and I've tried it. Unfortunately, it look like crystal reports does not understands the keyword `HasValue`. Is it that it is only in Crystal reports 8? I'm using Crystal Reports 10

Comment: It's weird, but CR 10 is a prior version to CR 2008. They stopped using incremental versions and switched to release years as their versioning scheme in 2008.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. As a reply to your EDIT, I tried this `if IsNull({?End Date}) then 
      {rectReport.Call date} in DateTimeValue('1753-01-01 00:00:00') to CurrentDateTime
    else   {rectReport.Call date} in {?Start Date} to {?End Date}
and 
if ({?Engine Down} = 3) then
        {rectReport.EngineDown} in 0 to 1`. Now it pops up an alert saying 'Date value cnat be blank'.

Comment: Right, the parameter will not be null since the user is forced to provide something or use the default values that you set. All you have to do is give {?Start Date} the default value of 1753-1-1, and {?End Date} the default value of CurrentDate and then select {rectReport.Calldate} in {?Start Date} to {?End Date} without any additional logic. This way the user can optionally choose to select new dates, but if they don't they'll just default.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I already tried that but it didnt work. I kept on searching round the net and discovered according to a guy at tec-tips.com that only string values are allowed to be left blank. I dont know how far this is true, but I've decided to make it compulsory for users to enter a date, pending when I get a better solution.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how default values of parameters work. If a user doesn't choose a date at run time, the value of the parameter won't be "blank" or null - it will be the default value that you, the report writer, have chosen previously. There is no need to check for null values in this scenario.

Comment: @Abimbola:  Yeah, what he said (Ryan).  I should have read all responses before I types mine above.  Sorry.

Comment: Guys, I perfectly understand what you are saying. The thing is I currently set the default start date  to `'1753-01-01 00:00:00'`. But when crystal reports renders it in the browser, it shows an input field blank and then a select field with the parameter value that I used. Unless I then select the parameter so that it enters into the input field, it prompts with a message saying `You must choose a date`.    I wish I could attach an image for you to see.

Comment: I hate to beat a dead horse, but something you said in your latest post made me wonder... you used the term "default values" to describe (what sounded like to me, anyway) the values available in the parameter drop-down as opposed to the actual default value for the parameter. I've never used CR in VS, but it seems odd that the default value wouldn't populate as it would in CR - in that case it wouldn't be any different from any other drop-down value, right? I just want to be sure we're on the same page when we're talking about "default values".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your particular situation, but the way we handle this (specifically for Defined Periods vs User-specified-Date-Range) is through being able to set defaults.

Our main environment is BOE XI.

Our parameters might be
   ReportPeriod  (String Variable)
and
   CustomDates   (DateTime Range, but will work as two discrete dates)

Example params for ReportPeriod might be
  1 Day
  7 Days
  Last Month
  Custom Dates

Formulas are used to calculate date limits that will be used in the record selection.  I start with the END DATE, as it is convenient for our period reports.

```
@EndDate
  Select ?ReportPeriod
    Case
       "1 Day", "7 Days"   : CurrentDate
          // Conveniently defaults to MIDNIGHT
       "Last Month"  : Maximum(LastFullMonth)
       "CustomDates" : Maximum(?CustomDates)
          // Or discrete parameter for end date
       default : CurrentDate

@BeginDate
  Select ?ReportPeriod
    Case
       "1 Day"  :  DateAdd("d", -1, @EndDate)
       "7 Days" :  DateAdd("d", -7, @EndDate)
       "Last Month"  : Minimum(LastFullMonth)
       "CustomDates" : Minimum(?CustomDates)
          // Or discrete parameter for end date
       default : DateAdd("d", -1, @EndDate)
```

And, let me caution against using CurentDateTime unless necessary.  Every time you try to step through the report, the selection will have changed:  5:01:10 PM ... 5:01:16 PM ... 5:01:24 PM ...

When publishing a report, we set default date (it doesn't matter what, it's only used for CUSTOM and the customer resets it then),    and a default ReportPeriod.

The report can be scheduled periodically (based on ReportPeriod) and it will always run.
If the user wants to do custom dates (historic reporting, etc.), then they can chose that for report period, and then set whatever start and end dates they need.

Helpful?

Comment: Thanks Marc, but I've been using Crystal reports 10 and I'm under a dead line to deliever. It would be suicidal to start learning a new tool now. If however you have a way around in Crystal Reports, I'd gladly welcome it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Abimbola, the formulas work @ the report level, and they work for CR10.  We deploy on XI R2, but the formulas work @ the report level.  I think I was trying to say, we set the defaults in the deployment tool, but a CR designer can set defaults to the parameters.  All this does for you is:  If the user pulls up and runs a report w/out specifying all parameters, there is a default so that the parameter is not empty.  Not a new tool, just a trick.

Comment: Ok Marc, I'd take a look at it again, Thanks